# Function to Create Random Number Not in Existing Table

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement, random

I am trying to populate a random number, that is not present in an existing range, into a cell.

The intention is to pick a question number from a problem set, but I do not wish to repeat the same problem again.

Each problem already completed is listed on a separate table column on sheet 2.

I'm wondering if I can use IF/THEN to keep running through random numbers until a value not present in the table column is populated in cell B10 on worksheet 1.

```
Function random_number_PS()

    Dim wrksht As Worksheet
    Dim tbl As ListObject
    Dim Random_Value As Integer

    Set wrksht = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")
    Set tbl = wrksht.ListObjects("Table1").ListColumns(1).DataBodyRange.Select

    Random_Value = Int((100 * Rnd) + 1)

        IF Random_Value 'this is where I am stuck

            Random_Value = Int((100 * Rnd) + 1)

        Else: ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("B10") = Random_Value

        End If

End Function
```

Here is the table in worksheet 2 that has the values I do not wish to repeat in the problem number column.

Table with exclusive Values 
[image]

Comment: Can you show an image of Sheet2?

Comment: Yes, absolutely. The initial post has been updated to include an image of the table on sheet 2, which contains the values that I do not want included in the randomize function.

Comment: Can you also show and image of the second table?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a function that should meet your needs, you call call as a function or in your worksheet e.g. `=RandNotInList(1, 100, B1:B100)`

```
Function RandNotInList(Low As Long, High As Long, ExcludesRange As Range) As Long    

Dim random As Long
Dim cell As Range

'loop until a random is generated that is not in the range (this should include error handling that is not implemented)
Do
    random = Low + Int(Rnd() * (High + 1 - Low))

    For Each cell In ExcludesRange
        If random = cell Then Exit For
    Next cell

Loop Until cell Is Nothing

RandNotInList = random

End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

This function will return a random number that isn't in your list - well, almost.

```
Function RandomNumber_PS() As Integer
    ' let your function return the random number found

    Dim Fun As Integer          ' this will be the function's return value
    Dim Ws As Worksheet
    Dim Fnd As Range
    Dim Tbl As Range
    Dim i As Integer

    Set Ws = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")
    Set Tbl = Ws.ListObjects("Table1").DataBodyRange.Columns(1)
    Randomize                   ' selects a random seed number

    Do
        Fun = Int((100 * Rnd) + 1)
        Set Fnd = Tbl.Find(Fun, LookAt:=xlWhole)
        ' leave the loop if Fun wasn't found in the table.
        If Fnd Is Nothing Then Exit Do
        i = i + 1                   ' emergency exit
    Loop While i < 300

    If i = 300 Then
        MsgBox "I haven't been able to find a random number.", _
               vbInformation, "Failure notice"
    End If

    RandomNumber_PS = Fun
End Function
```

As you come toward the end of choices you can offer - if your system ever allows such an occurrence to occur - it may be better to create a list of available numbers and pick one of them at random. If you decide to do that the question will arise why you don't do it from the outset, for all.

The system would be to create an array of all available numbers, say `Arr = Array(1,3,7,13)` and then pick a random index. In this case pick a number between 1 and 4 and your random number is Arr(rnd). I shall program this and add it to my reply after lunch.

Here is the promised variation.

```
Function RandomNumber_PS2() As Integer
    ' let your function return the random number found

    Const RandomLimit As Integer = 100      ' reset to suit

    Dim Ws As Worksheet
    Dim TblRng As Range
    Dim Fnd As Range
    Dim Arr As Variant, Lst() As Integer
    Dim Idx As Integer
    Dim R As Long

    Set Ws = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")
    Set TblRng = Ws.ListObjects("Table1").DataBodyRange.Columns(1)

    ReDim Lst(1 To RandomLimit)
    Arr = TblRng.Value
    For R = 1 To RandomLimit
        Set Fnd = TblRng.Find(R, LookAt:=xlWhole)
        If Fnd Is Nothing Then
            Idx = Idx + 1
            Lst(Idx) = R
        End If
    Next R
    ReDim Preserve Lst(1 To Idx)

    Select Case Idx
        Case 0
            MsgBox "There are no more tasks to alot.", _
                   vbInformation, "Failure notice"
        Case 1
            RandomNumber_PS2 = Lst(1)
        Case Else
            Randomize                   ' selects a random seed number
            RandomNumber_PS2 = Lst(Int((Idx * Rnd) + 1))
    End Select
End Function
```

BTW, you could deploy the solution as a UDF and call the function from the worksheet:

Sheet2![B10] `=RandomNumber_PS2()`